# ActiveRecord association between exactly 2 objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a `Conversation` model I want to associate between exactly two users.

It doesn't seem intuitive for the Conversation to `belong_to` a single user with another user as its foreign key. `has_and_belongs_to_many` seems like overkill.

What's the best way to connect a model between exactly 2 instances of another model?

Comment: This is kind of confusing sounding. You want one *instance* of a `Conversation` associated between exactly two users? Or you want the entire class associated between those two users, so no other users in your system can have any conversations?

Comment: Each Conversation takes place between 2 Users. There are many Users and as many conversations as there are unique combinations of Users.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem intuitive, but that is how I would do it.

Conversation with 2 user ids, like, user1_id and user2_id, and then, in the Conversation model, I would give 2 different names for each belongs to:

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :speaker, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'user1_id'
  belongs_to :listener, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'user2_id'
  ...
  def users
    [speaker, listener].compact
  end
  ...
  def efficient_users
    User.where(id: [user1_id, user2_id])
  end
  ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks.. is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Does this look sound?

```
class User
 has_many :relationships
 has_many :conversations, through: relationships

class Relationship
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :conversation

class Conversation
 has_many :relationships #just has 2
```